# How to type the $\dashint$ symbol on this site?

Tags: support, mathjax

How to type the symbol $\dashint$ on this site?
It looks like the following:

[image]

Thank you!

---

**Edit:**

As @Jack hinted in the comment, we may use

```
\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}
```

to render
$$
\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}
$$
on this site.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/931977/9464

Comment: @Jack Thank you!

Comment: Also related: [How to type average integral?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12561)